# Media Query Hide Desktop Viewport

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

You can view the coding I'm using on my live site (www.randolphlibrary.org/mobilesite.htm)

TLDR: How to implement the list-view style when people look at something with a view port of max-width 768px so that it applies to my mobile users?

So my idea was to take this code to it to the header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.css" media="(max-width: 768px)"/>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
```

But, the  problem is how to make the mobile device realize to use that jquery stylesheet and not the "default" CSS stylesheet already in place below this code?

Someone mentioned just making a media query with @media= "(max-width: 768px) { display:none; } But I get no purchase.

This feels like such a basic issue, but I'm stuck. Even when I go into the "default" CSS and add display:none; to the body it doesn't do anything.

Any pointers would be beyond greatly appreciated. I'm trying to make a small town library look more appealing to our youth out there who don't look up from their phones.

UPDATE: The guy teaching me this explained that for a very basic jQuery Mobile page we needed 3 files in the head: CSS file to make jQuery work, Javascript file that makes jQuery work and a Javascript file that appends to the core jQuery file that provides additional widgets for mobile devices (jQuery Mobile).

So, with the 3 files shown above I thought I was golden. But still have issues.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to share some of your Jquery code by any chance? I think i can help you out, just need to see what you are working with. At first glance it looks like you can handle this within the jquery file to only run the code when the window is at a certain width, which is what you need.

Comment: Sorry for such a late response on my part. Weirdly I only got a message about a response to my question 2 days ago on my email. The jQuery code I have is just from the guy who was teaching me this. I have three links as seen above that are the only things that deal with jQuery. When I click on them in view page source or on my text editor it's the same vast amount of wildness I can't discern what the hell it is.